# disable column edit on datatables.js inline editor tab between columns

Tags: datatables

i'm trying to use datatables.js inline editor tab between columns https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/tabControl.html and their example works fine, what i can't seem to figure out is how do i disable a column that i do not want to inline edit ?

example on website

```
table.on( 'key-focus', function ( e, datatable, cell ) {
    editor.inline( cell.index() );
});
```

i've tried to change to

```
table.on( 'key-focus', 'td.editable', function ( e, datatable, cell ) {
    editor.inline( cell.index() );
});
```

so it targets only TD's that have the class editable .. but it does not work ..

anyway if someone used this before i would appreciate a hint :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer eventually ... and it can be done in 2 ways

1) it seems that the datatables editor will add a .focus class on the TD element that's being edited at that moment, so we can do something like

```
if($('.data.table .focus').hasClass('noedit')) { ...
```

where "noedit" is your class that u want to add to the TD to signal that the cell is not editable

2) another way i found was playing with the examples from docs however it seems more complicated than it should be ..

```
if($(datatable.cell(cell.index()).nodes()).hasClass('noedit')) { ...
```

hope it will help someone ..